# Reading a symbol value without using eval

Tags: scheme, eval

This is probably something really trivial, but I
can't figure out which is the right way to go.

Assume we have the following `define`s

```
(define foo1 "asd")
(define foo2 "qwe")
(define foo3 "zxc")
(define foo4 "rte")
(define foo5 "qlx")
```

and then

```
(define foos 
  '(foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 foo5))
```

What I want is to get a list that contains
the values of `foo.` symbols.

So far, what I am doing is the following 
(i.e. in guile):

```
(define (foovals lst)
  (map (λ (x) (eval x (interaction-environment))) lst))

(foovals foos)
```

which returns the list I want:

```
("asd" "qwe" "zxc" "rte" "qlx")
```

What I'd like to ask is:
Is there an alternative approach? I.e. without having to
use `eval` in the first place?

Comment: What is your motivation for not using `eval`?  It is designed exactly for what your are looking for.  Plus it is part of RnRS.

Comment: @GoZoner I was mostly wondering if I was using the right approach or if there was another (more appropriate) way to do it (assuming that I cannot modify the initial `define`s). I.e. an alternative to getting a symbol's value.

Comment: The limitation on `eval` is that only expressions are required to work.  Thus `(eval '(define foo "abc") ...)` can't be counted on (as a definition is not an expression).

Comment: What's the matter with `(define foos 
  (list foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 foo5))`?

Comment: @JoshuaTaylor Well, the initial list was the quoted one (and I was also interested in the symbol names, e.g. symbol name -> file name, symbol value -> "contents after processing"). Of course you are absolutely right! I could always get the two lists (quoted and non-quoted) and `zip` them together (while `symbol->string` the first one) and work with that :) I do suspect that there are several other ways of getting a list of `((symbol-name symbol-value)...)` that I don't know / can't think of (P.S. the `foovals` is actually part of the `(symbol-name symbol-value)` generation part).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no standard Scheme way to do what you're seeking to do. However, *some* Scheme implementations provide (implementation-specific) ways to access module/top-level variables. (These don't provide access to lexical (local) variables, only top-level ones.)

Here's how you might do this [in Guile](http://www.gnu.org/software/guile/manual/html_node/Module-System-Reflection.html):

```
(use-modules (srfi srfi-26))
(define (foovals lst)
  (map (cut module-ref (current-module) <>) lst))
```

Note that `module-ref` and `current-module` are Guile-specific and will not work in other Scheme implementations.

Comment: I see how this is a Guile version of the OP's code, but I don't see anything in the question that explains the problem with `(define foos 
  (list foo1 foo2 foo3 foo4 foo5))`.  Isn't that a simpler solution?